# Disable error in vbs

Tags: vbscript

i use this code for download a link , but **if objXMLHTTP.Status not 200** then script show error that can't download or not found link &...
How can add command that if objXMLHTTP.Status not 200 , script don't show any error?

```
function download(sFileURL, sLocation)

'create xmlhttp object
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

'get the remote file
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, false

'send the request
objXMLHTTP.send()

'wait until the data has downloaded successfully
do until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 :  wcript.sleep(1000) :  loop

'if the data has downloaded sucessfully
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then

        'create binary stream object
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open

        'adTypeBinary
    objADOStream.Type = 1
    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody

        'Set the stream position to the start
    objADOStream.Position = 0    

        'create file system object to allow the script to check for an existing file
        Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        'check if the file exists, if it exists then delete it
    If objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation

        'destroy file system object
    Set objFSO = Nothing

        'save the ado stream to a file
    objADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation

        'close the ado stream
    objADOStream.Close

    'destroy the ado stream object
    Set objADOStream = Nothing

'end object downloaded successfully
End if

'destroy xml http object
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

End function

download "http://remote-location-of-file", "C:\name-of-file-and-extension"

Answer (score 0):

Your code  misses the end function and you have an error at the line with wcript.sleep,  without comments to be concise it should be something like

```
function download(sFileURL, sLocation, async)
  set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  objXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, async
  on error resume next
  objXMLHTTP.send()
  if err.number = 0 then
    if objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1
      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    
      set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      if objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) then
        objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation
      end if
      set objFSO = Nothing
      objADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      set objADOStream = Nothing
      download = true
    end if
  else
    download = false
  end if
  set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
end function

if download("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782976/disable-error-in-vbs", "question.html", false) then
  wscript.echo "download ok"
else
  wscript.echo "download nok"
end if
```

Comment: your "wcript.sleep(1000)" shows that you never tested your code against an Url that fails; in that case, the "Until Status = 200" loop will never terminate. .SaveToFile has a secod parameter, so you can avoid the ugly oFS. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: thanks Ekkehard, you'r partially right, i did test it with a bad URL but the loop is never reached, the script stopped after the .send, perhaps because of the async false I modified the code and did testing on both existing an non-existing url . In a OOP language as Ruby i would return the file itself by the function and otherwise nil, here i have to do with true or false

Answer (score 0):

See my other answer about the errors in your code.
This is a more concise version using the overwrite parameter so no check with fso needed.

```
function download2(url, destination)
  download2 = false
  on error resume next
  set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  xml.Open "GET", url, False
  xml.Send
  if err.number = 0 then
    if xml.readystate = 4 then
      if xml.status = 200 then 
        set oStream = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
        const adTypeBinary = 1,  adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2, adSaveCreateNotExist = 1 
        oStream.type = adTypeBinary
        oStream.open
        oStream.write xml.responseBody
        oStream.saveToFile destination, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        oStream.close
        set oStream = nothing
        download2 = true
      end if
    end if
  end if
  set xml = Nothing
end function

if download2("http://www.textpad.com/download/v60/txpeng600.zig", "txpeng600.zip") then
  wscript.echo "download ok"
else
  wscript.echo "download nok"
end if

'download nok
```

Comment: "err.number" won't be set without an "On Error Resume Next", which should be accompanied by a corresponding "On Error GoTo 0". Please don't add versions of your answer/code, but delete this and edit/improve the other one.

Comment: again partially right, an on error resume next is needed somewhere in the code is needed so i added one but an on error goto 0, that depends on your way of working. Since i do a lot of error trapping, logging and debugging in my code resume next is usually on. about publishing 2 answers, what's wrong with that ? they differ enough and it makes easier reading and commenting

Comment: idealiter, each question here should have the one and only correct answer; in practice there may be more than one suitable solution for one problem. So it's ok, if different people post different (correct!) answers. But posting variations of the same idea (each with problems of its own) just creates a mess. Surely you can come up with something usable in one answer.

Comment: @Ekkehard, this site is about learning and helping people, so i suggest you propose your own solution in stead of breaking off those of people who do care

Comment: erroneous code doesn't help people. Because of the wrong use of OERN, download2() will return true, if you pass a non writeable destination, the status check got lost; download()'s third parameter is a booby trap, the misplaced OERN prevents catching bad sFileUrls, it still contains the FSO roundabout. And no - you needn't be willing or able to do better for being entitled to point out mistakes.

Comment: as i said, go ahead and publish your solution, this all is beyond the question of the OP who merely wanted to get his errors away, which i pinpointed, to get the perfect solution it would make days of discussions between specialists and i doubt if they'd ever concur