# Vb Script or VBA code to copy the contents of a web webpage to a word/excel sheet

Tags: vba, vbscript, copy, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract values from HTML TD and Tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776484/extract-values-from-html-td-and-tr)

I need to copy the contents of a web webpage to a word/excel sheet using VBA or VB Script (If it hectic the using any programming language)..

So if i give the path of a web page then the system needs to copy the contents of a web page and write it in a Word or excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Please post what you allready have next time, i have 2 solutions, choose what best suits your needs, here the one that use word as requested

```
Option Explicit
'Just change these two lines
Const HTMLFileIn="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782976/disable-error-in-vbs"
Const DocFileOut="c:\newfile.doc"

Dim MyWord,oIE
set MyWord=CreateObject("Word.Document") 
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate HTMLFileIn
Wscript.Sleep 500
oIE.document.body.createTextRange.execCommand("Copy")
Wscript.Sleep 500
MyWord.Content.Paste
MyWord.SaveAs DocFileOut
MyWord.Close
oIE.Quit
Set oIE = Nothing
set MyWord = Nothing 
Wscript.Echo HTMLFileIn & " is now saved as " & DocFileOut

Sub wait
  Wscript.Sleep 500
  While oIE.busy
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
  Wend
  While oIE.Document.readyState <> "complete"
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
  Wend
End Sub
```

If you just want to view the html, here is the simplest solution

```
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782976/disable-error-in-vbs"
set xml = createobject("msxml2.serverxmlhttp.6.0")
with xml
  .open "get", url, false
  .send
  wscript.echo .responsetext
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

See my other answer that uses word.
And here another technique and a save as HTML

```
function download(sFileURL, sLocation, async)
  set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  objXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, async
  on error resume next
  objXMLHTTP.send()
  if err.number = 0 then
    do until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200
      wscript.echo objXMLHTTP.Status
      wcript.sleep(200)
    loop
    if objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1
      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    
      set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      If objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation
      Set objFSO = Nothing
      objADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      set objADOStream = Nothing
      download = true
    end if
  else
    download = false
  end if
  set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
end function

if download("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782976/disable-error-in-vbs", "question.html", false) then
  wscript.echo "download ok"
else
  wscript.echo "download nok"
end if
```