# Internet Explorer GetElementByID generates "The object invoked has disconnected from its client."

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

This code was able to run on my home laptop but not my work laptop.

```
Sub Autologin()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "my_url"
    IE.Document.GetElementByID("j_username").Value = "my_username"`
```

The error occurs on the last line.

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>   Automation error, The object invoked has disconnected from its client.

Comment: It sounds a little bit naive but do you have Internet Explorer installed on your work laptop?

Comment: Yes. The url opens fine on internet explorer but it doesn't input anything in the username box and the error message appears. Thanks

Comment: This maybe because of my lack of knowledge but are you trying to `GetElementByID` and assigning a value to it? it thought `GetElementByID` returned an object? how can it be assigned a value? Also then you are not capturing what is being returned?

Comment: Can you open other URLs with the same code (i.e. www.google.com)? If so, I'd try running Excel as administrator and see if it works that way.  Cursory searching points to an IE permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks Comintern. I didn't expect that but it isn't opening most other urls. Running as administrator doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks Zac, I'm not certain but from looking at other similar scripts, the method above of =  "my username" works, this exact code works on my home laptop too.

Comment: Just realised that it would work because you are calling for the element and then assigning a value to the ID of that element. Not sure if this would make much difference but have you tried referencing IE in your project rather than creating an `InternetExplorer.Application`?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23232573/2165759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
Dim mainDoc As HTMLDocument 
Set mainDoc = IE.document
```

'This Is the where you add the id Name of the control you want To Access. You can find the id Name by searching through the source via ‘View – Source’ In Internet Explorer.

```
mainDoc.all("j_username").value="my_username"

Set IE = Nothing
Set mainDoc = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this a go:

```
Dim mainDoc As HTMLDocument
Set mainDoc = IE.document
```

'This Is the where you add the id Name of the control you want To Access.  You can find the id Name by searching through the source via ‘View – Source’ In Internet Explorer.

```
mainDoc.all("j_username").value="my_username"

Set IE = Nothing
Set mainDoc = Nothing
```