# Get reference to Internet Explorer document object

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, runtime-error, browser-automation

I want to access Internet Explorer using VBA.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim i As IHTMLDocument
Dim d As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "www.google.com"
Set d = ie.Document
```

I want to use intellisense that is why instead of going for `ie.document.get` I am using this method.

Getting error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't related with intellisense. All you need is to wait until navigating is completed and IE is ready before accessing document:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim i As IHTMLDocument
    Dim d As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.google.com"
        Do While .ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Set d = .Document
    End With

End Sub
```

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23232573/2165759) answer.