# Cannot access webpage button

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I want to click on a web page button via an excel button. After inspecting the element (which is the button), I get the following HTML code:

```
class="mstrLargeIconViewItemLink" onclick="return submitLink(this, event);" href="mstrWeb?evt=3010&amp;src=mstrWeb.3010&amp;loginReq=true&amp;Server=L-MIS01&amp;ServerAlias=L-MIS01%2FL-MIS02%2FL-MIS03&amp;Project=MIS+International&amp;Port=0">
```

I opened the main page where the button lies and tried every solution I could find on the interenet (expecially multiple versions of `Document.getElementById()`) but none worked.

The code I have is shown below (very basic until this point):

```vb
Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate2 "https://mis.lidl.net/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb"
IE.document.getElementbyID("mstrLargeIconViewItemName").href
```

Comment: Navigate2 is asynchronous, you must wait for the document to fully load. The _DocumentComplete event is best for this, alternatively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232488/detect-when-a-web-page-is-loaded-without-using-sleep

Comment: Also try `Set objButton = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("mstrLargeIconViewItemName")(0)`