# Save texts on webpages (1000 pages)

Tags: text, web-scraping

I have 1000 of URLs. I need a tools that get my URLs and export all the text that appears on those pages. 
I need the texts that a is shown on the webpages, not the background html code.

Do you know any software or way to do it?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21490198/2165759)

Comment: `lynx` maybe? http://lynx.browser.org

Comment: @MarkSetchell - lynx is ancient and cannot render javascript. The modern option is phantomjs

Comment: @npocmaka Ok, thanks for the tip - kids calls me "dinosaur" too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save this as bat file (i.e. `innerTextGet.bat`):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
        @echo off 

        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %* 
        ::pause
        exit /b %errorlevel% 

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */ 


var link=WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var saveTo=WScript.Arguments.Item(1);


var IE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application"); 
IE.Visible=false;
IE.Navigate2(link);

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

var counter=0;
while (IE.Busy && counter<60*60*10) {
    //WScript.Echo(IE.Busy);
    sleep(1000);
    counter++;
}

if(IE.Busy){
    WScript.Echo("Cant wait 4ever");
    WScript.Quit(10);
}

function writeContent(file,content) {
        var ado = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
        ado.Type = 2;  // adTypeText = 2
        ado.CharSet = "iso-8859-1";  // right code page for output (no adjustments)
        //ado.Mode=2;
        ado.Open();

        ado.WriteText(content);
        ado.SaveToFile(file, 2);
        ado.Close();    
}

var innerText=IE.document.body.innerText;
IE.Quit();
writeContent(saveTo,innerText);
```

And use it like:

```
call innerTextGet.bat "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611374/save-texts-on-webpages-1000-pages"  result.txt
```

It is not fail safe - does not check if the result file already exists if the parameters are correctly passed and so on, but it works at least. It again uses `innerText` property of `InternetExplorer.Application` object as proposed by **@omegastripes** though I prefer jscript because it is easier to be plugged into batch file.

As you gave no information about where the links are stored I assume you know how to read and iterate through them.