# VBA: Copy data/text from an existing open Internet Explorer tab

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a VBA code which allows me to copy data from an existing open IE tab maybe by sending a <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> with `SendKey` method and then pasting it to a sheet on Excel.
I have tried "Get Data from Web" but that doesn't work since I need to enter username/password and can't setup a `getElementbyId` lines.
So I found some code, that scans the open tabs of an already active Internet explorer session, but I want to make VBA Switch to the tab that matched and Copy the text from this website.

```
Sub AAA()

    marker = 0
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
    For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
        my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title
        If my_url Like "http://www.cnn.com" & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
            Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
            marker = 1
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next
    If marker = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
    Else
        'Switch to the tab that matched and Copy the text from this website..
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you would be happier skipping the user interface copy-paste method and instead go to the temporary internet files and find the .html document instead.  Tell me if you have already ruled this method out!

Comment: Could you please provide actual URL and expected output? That might be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @omegastripes, unfortunately I can't, it's an intranet address.
elliotsvensson,  I have not, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Anyway, you could share HTML content (the relevent part with cleaned up sensitive data), and expected output.

Comment: How do I get the HTML content? I navigated to the temp internet folder. I don't see HTML type in the files

Comment: why are you not already in the right window/tab? Have you clicked on something that has led you to a new window/tab?

Comment: Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21490198/2165759).

Comment: @Qharr, no I haven't. This is an already open webpage.
I just can't switch to it and sendkey to "select all" on this particular tab

Comment: And you can't navigate to this tab/webpage using IE because of login issues?

Comment: IMO better to refuse from `SendKeys` as most unreliable. Get a reference to the IE with opened workpage `Application` object, and work directly with DOM.

Comment: @sagittarius_88 You can get the HTML content of the webpage by the following steps: in IE navigate to the target webpage, press F12, go to DOM Explorer tab, find root `<html>` tag, right click on it, choose copy in context menu. Take a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeLgT.png). Then you may paste the copied HTML content to a notepad, make some cleanups if necessary, and share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is one way to get the handle of the IE

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ShellApp As Object, ShellWindows As Object
    Dim objIE As Object, objWin As Object
    Dim ieCaption As String

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()

    '~~> Loop through the windows and check if it is IE
    For Each objWin In ShellWindows
        If (Not objWin Is Nothing) Then
            ieCaption = objWin.Name
            If ieCaption = "Internet Explorer" Then
                Set objIE = objWin
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    '~~> If IE is found then wirk with that object
    If Not objIE Is Nothing Then
        With objIE
            Debug.Print .Document.Body.Innerhtml
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```